# how to add multiple jar(s) to classpath?

Tags: java, classpath

I am having more than 25 jar files how to add all of them in a classpath?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Separate them with a colon / semicolon  (`:` / `;`) on *nix / win

But it would be way easier to use an IDE (Eclipse, NetBeans) to handle the classpath for you.

Comment: That's a semicolon :) Use a semicolon on Windows, a colon on *NIX.

Answer (score 9):

If all the jar files are in the same folder, as of jdk6, Java supports classpath wildcards.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

So you can use something like,

> /path/to/jar/*

Also consider having a separate classpath for each project.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, if the classpath is so big that you can't put this on a command line, you can set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable (which should be set to the semicolon-separated list of JARs).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html) to manage your dependencies. It'll go a long way to prevent JAR-hell.

Comment: Ant can be an alternative for this matter

Comment: I'd argue that you'd need ant + ivy for feature parity with maven.

Answer (score 0):

I use eclipse, so there is a for me to first put them into a folder.
After which if I need to add it to build path, I just go to the build path option to browse to the folder and select all.
You can also import them easily by browsing to the folder and select all too.