# No suitable driver found for jdbc exception despite adding mysql-connector-java dependency to Maven

Tags: java, mysql, maven

I created a new Amazon AWS Ubuntu 16.04 instance and installed mysql-server, JDK 8, and Maven. That's it, nothing else was installed. However, after creating a simple test database a trying to run a simple Java program(provided below) that accessed that test database to make sure mysql was working okay, I got the infamous `No suitable driver found for jdbc` exception. This doesn't make any sense since I'm using JDK 8 and have `mysql-connector-java` added as a dependency. I've been clicking on tens of similair SO posts all day, trying out the most often proposed solutions to no avail. The commonly recommend solutions I've tried out include:

1. Verified that the MySQL connection string conforms to the proper syntax.
2. Tried using `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();` , which I'm pretty certain I don't need because I'm using JDK 8 and [JDK 6 or higher feature "autoloading of JDBC drivers"](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefjdbc4_0summary.html), making Class.forName() unnecessary.

Here's the simple database I created

```
mysql>create database moviedbtest;
mysql>use moviedbtest;
mysql>create table moviestars(
          id varchar(10) primary key,
          name varchar(100) not null,
          birthYear integer
       );
mysql> INSERT INTO moviestars VALUES('145061', 'Angelina Jolie', 1975);
mysql> INSERT INTO moviestars VALUES('855017', 'Clint Eastwood', 1930);
```

Here's my Maven POM.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdbc-test-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Here is the simple Java test program

```
import java.sql.*;
public class JDBC1 {

    public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {

        //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:///moviedbtest?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "mytestuser" , "mypassword");


        Statement select = connection.createStatement();
        String query = "Select * from moviestars";
        ResultSet result = select.executeQuery(query);

        ResultSetMetaData metadata = result.getMetaData();
        System.out.println("There are " + metadata.getColumnCount() + " columns");

        }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The infamous java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911253/the-infamous-java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found)

Comment: @JanezKuhar The first suggestion doesn't apply since I don't have any server installed, and therefore no lib folder. The second suggestion doesn't seem to apply either since I'm quite sure my JDBC connection url is following the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. I had to add the path of the 'mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar' to my classpath via the command line when executing the program, [using a : to separate the multiple jar files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387534/how-to-add-multiple-jars-to-classpath), like so: `java -cp jdbc-test-project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.38/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar JDBC1` .